# Kubernetes NGINX ingress only ever returning default back end, not any of the other ingress rules set up

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am deploying our system onto AKS, using kubectl. 
I have the following deployed:

Namespace: kube-system
- Kubernetes NGINX controller 
- Default back end

Namespace: default
- 3 ingress objects, each consisting of multiple rules. Each is bound to a different sub domain. When I ping the sub domains the correct IP is set (i.e. the ingress controller)
- The services which are to be accessed are also deployed in this namespace.

The ingress controller has created successfully, received and EIP etc and when I go to this IP I get the default back end. So far so good.

However, I then start to add the Ingress objects - all looks good in the ingress controller logs, adding the rules and reloading the back end with all appropriate rules however when i then try to access any of the new URLs, i.e. 
http://ingress1.ourdomain.com/ingressrule1 the request just times out.

I have set the level of debugging up to v3 on the ingress controller and all looks as expected in the logs. The only thing I can think of is that the controller and ingress & associated services are in different namespaces? But this seems to be the correct way to set this up. I have trawled many web pages now, and although the docs at: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/how-it-works/ and https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/troubleshooting/ are helpful they haven't provided and clues for my situation.

Has anyone come across anything similar at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timeout issues are usually related to network (security groups) problems

Can you make sure the port 80 is open on the security group of the instance that has the EIP your are pointing to ?

Comment: Correct. Absolute school boy error! I forgot I'd had to recreate my cluster due to AKS corrupting it ;) Many thanks.

Comment: I am curious as to how I could access the default back end even with the SG locked down though. The only difference is that the default back end was in the kube-system namespace....